# What comes out of this bump in this vegetable?

Tags: identification, vegetables

I live in Denmark, Europe and I have in my garden this gigantic vegetable.

It has a big bump on the top and i was wondering about what comes out of it?

[image]

Comment: Likely Elephant garlic? or Allium ampeloprasum, to give it its proper name. Definitely an Allium either way - it has a rounded head of pink flowers, though some can be white.

Comment: Wow. I'm surprised a pore can also provide garlics. Are they edible?

Comment: Sorry Harshani, but I'm not sure what you mean by 'pore' - the meaning in English is a tiny opening, either in skin or on a leaf, principally to allow moisture to escape. I changed it to plant in your question... and the garlic bulb is at the bottom, under the ground, its part of the root system.

Comment: A pore is a vegetable. See here: http://www.fruit-vegetable.info/pore.htm

Comment: Erm, no, its not - the translation into English on that page you've linked to is off the wall I'm afraid, meaning very bad, there are other errors in it too. Pore can also mean to study intently, as in 'pore over'....

Comment: How can i then find the english translation for this vegetable? In danish its called a "porre".

Comment: Found the name - its a "Leek" in english.

Comment: Break off a piece and smell it. If it smells like onions, it's potentially a leek. If it smells like garlic, it's probably a garlic plant. One might think leeks generally have more tubular leaves, because they taste like onions, which have tubular leaves. Leeks and garlic can both look like your picture. Onions, chives and shallots look different (with tubular leaves). Leek leaves actually can be flat, and the flowers actually can be really pointy like that before blooming. The base of the plant and/or the bulbs are the main difference, it would seem. (The bulbs look much different.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't put any more comments, thread's too long. I think this plant is Elephant Garlic, or Allium ampeloprasum. The thing on the top is going to be a flower, usually pink - the part most people are interested in is what's under the ground, the garlic bulb, which should be very large. And yes, you can harvest the bulb and use it to cook with. Leaves and flowers are also edible, but will become tough if not picked young.

If you want to harvest the bulb, dig up the plant and lay it sideways, chop off the leaves and stem, leaving about an inch or two of stem attached to the bulb, and hang it up till it dries out.

Leek is Allium porrum - it may be that the 'pore' you speak of is taken from the last part of the Latin name for that particular vegetable.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I got this garden some months ago and when i got it the leeks were already there. I dont know much about them so im happy to hear all of them is edible. I might try to dig one up to see whats underground.

Comment: Ok - but this is not a leek! It's related, in the same family of flora, but quite different from a leek in taste and culinary use. If you do dig it up, you're supposed to leave the foliage in place and hang up or lay the plant sideways to dry out.

Comment: What name should i edit into my question then?

Comment: Don't worry about it - you asked what the plant was, that was the original query - you could say is this a vegetable?

Comment: Thanks Bamboo. Do you know what they taste like?

Comment: Well its garlic! Mild garlic flavour to this one - used the world over for flavouring in cooking. You wouldn't normally eat it on its own, but chop up bits to put in a dish you're making - like bolognese sauce or whatever. If you ate the whole bulb, raw or cooked, everyone else would leave home for a week - you'd reek of garlic,the smell comes out of your skin and from your breath!

Comment: Sounds tasty. I will try that:)